# Label lines in a plot

Tags: r, plot

I am plotting two lines using

```
plot(x, y, type = "l", color = "red")
```

and

```
points(x2, y2, type = "l", color = "blue")
```

I want to be able to add a label next to each line (instead of a legend).
I am pretty sure it is possible using the package in http://directlabels.r-forge.r-project.org/.

Yet, I don't find an easy way of doing that.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use the `locator()` within `text()` by point&click method.

```
y <- rnorm(100, 10)
y2 <- rnorm(100, 20)
x <- 1:100

plot(x, y, type = "n", ylim = c(0, 40), xlim = c(0, 120))
lines(x, y)
lines(x, y2, col = "red")
text(locator(), labels = c("red line", "black line)"))
```

[image]

Answer (score 14):

Instead of using locator(), you could also just make the label coordinates a function of your data. For example, piggy backing on Roman's demo:

```
text(x=rep(max(x)+3, 2), y=c(mean(y), mean(y2)), pos=4, labels=c('black line', 'red line'))
```

Comment: Some times `pos` should be set appropriately.

Answer (score 5):

`locator()` is an interactive method of obtaining coordinates by clicking on an existing graph.

Here are instructions on how to use `locator()` to find the right coordinates for a label on a graph.

**Step 1:** Plot a graph:

```
plot(1:100)
```

**Step 2:** Type the following into the console:

```
coords <- locator()
```

**Step 3:** Click once on the plot, then click `Stop .. Stop Locator` at the top left of the plot (this returns control back to the R console).

**Step 4:** Find the returned coordinates:

```
coords
$x
[1] 30.26407
$y
[1] 81.66773
```

**Step 5:** Now, you can add a label to the existing plot using these coordinates:

```
text(x=30.26407, y=81.66773,label="This label appears where I clicked")
```

or

```
text(x=coords$x, y=coords$y,label="This label appears where I clicked")
```

Here is the result:

[image]

You'll notice that the label appears with its center where you clicked. Its better if the label appears with its first character where you clicked. To find the correct parameter, see the help for `text`, and add the parameter `pos=4`:

```
text(x=30,y=80,pos=4,label = "hello")
```

Notes:

- The label appears in the same x,y coordinates as dots on the graph. So, **x=100,y=0** would appear on the **lower right**, while **x=0,y=100** would appear on the **upper left**.
- Can also use `legend()` to plot a label (this draws a box around the label which often looks nicer).
- See [How to change font family in a legend in an R-plot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7136990/change-font-in-a-legend) for how to change the font in a legend, and how to auto-place the legend on the top right of the graph.
- I would recommend becoming familiar with `ggplot2` instead of plot, as `ggplot2` is the gold standard for producing graphs.

Answer (score 3):

To use directlabels, you must structure your data in a data.frame and then use a high-level plotting system like ggplot2, or in the example below, lattice:

```
y <- rnorm(100, 10)
y2 <- rnorm(100, 20)
x <- 1:100
treatment <- rep(c("one group","another"),each=length(x))
df <- data.frame(x=c(x,x),y=c(y,y2),treatment)
library(lattice)
p <- xyplot(y~x,df,groups=treatment,type="l")
if(!require(directlabels)){
  install.packages("directlabels")
  library(directlabels)
}
print(direct.label(p))
print(direct.label(update(p,xlim=c(0,120)),last.points))
```