# How to change the default label font type to italic in radarchart ("fmsb" package)?

Tags: r, fonts, label, radar-chart, italic

I have created a radar chart for showing the variation of Cultural Indexes (CI) of a number of species with respect to the location. However, since species names must be written in italic or underlined, I need to change the default font type used for the label items. I have been searching internet for many days how to do it without succes. It seems that the [question has been asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30240161/radar-chart-i-e-spider-plot-and-italic-font-in-r) but no substantial answers. I would appreciate any help please.
Here is the my [data](https://www.dropbox.com/s/s2pnccj4uvzx9kl/data.txt?dl=0) and this is the code:

```
library(fmsb)
colors_border=c( rgb(0.2,0.5,0.5,0.9), rgb(0.8,0.2,0.5,0.9) , rgb(0.7,0.5,0.1,0.9))
colors_in=c(rgb(0.2,0.5,0.5,0.3), rgb(0.8,0.2,0.5,0.3) , rgb(0.7,0.5,0.1,0.3))
radarchart( data  , axistype=1 , pcol=colors_border, pfcol=colors_in, plwd=2.5, plty=1, cglcol="grey", cglty=1, axislabcol="grey40", caxislabels=seq(0,1,0.25), cglwd=0.8, calcex = 0.8, vlabels = c("A. pubescens", "A. alboviolaceum", "A. angustifolium", "A. melegueta", "C. anisata", "C. giganteus", "L. chevalieri", "M. myristica", "P. guineense", "S. longipedunculata",  "T. sanguinea", "U. chamae", "X. aethiopica", "Z. zanthoxyloides"), vlcex=0.8)
legend(x=1.3, y=1.2, legend = rownames(data[-c(1,2),]), bty = "n", pch=20, col=colors_border, text.col = "grey25", cex=0.8, pt.cex=1.5)
```

`radarchart()` output:

[image: radarchart() output]

Answer (score 7):

I finally found the solution. All we need is to set the family and font plotting parameters to the values we want before calling `radarchart()`. This can be done via `par()`.

### Setting the default font family

```
op <- par(family = "Times New Roman", font=3)
colors_border=c( rgb(0.2,0.5,0.5,0.9), rgb(0.8,0.2,0.5,0.9), rgb(0.7,0.5,0.1,0.9))
colors_in=c(rgb(0.2,0.5,0.5,0.3), rgb(0.8,0.2,0.5,0.3),
rgb(0.7,0.5,0.1,0.3))
```

### Plotting the radarchart

```
radarchart( data  , axistype=1,pcol=colors_border, pfcol=colors_in,
plwd=2.5, plty=1, cglcol="grey", cglty=1, axislabcol="grey40",
caxislabels=seq(0,1,0.25), cglwd=0.8, calcex = 0.8, vlcex=0.8, vlabels = c("A. pubescens", "A. alboviolaceum", "A. angustifolium", "A. melegueta", "C. anisata", "C. giganteus", "L. chevalieri", "M. tenuifolia", "P. guineense", "S. lonipedunculata", "T. sanguinea", "U. chamae", "X. aethiopica", "Z. zanthoxyloides"))
```

### reset plotting parameters

`par(op)`

The above code produces:
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ev5ho.png)

Source: [How to change font family in a legend in an R-plot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7136990/how-to-change-font-family-in-a-legend-in-an-r-plot)

Comment: (+1 for the great answer). if anyone wishes to use it, please add the line `par(family = "Times New Roman")` just before plotting the figure. While saving a figure, I wrote the statement before saving statement and at that time, it did not work.