# Can't display Chinese characters in R plot

Tags: r, plot, encoding, utf-8, chinese-locale

Chinese characters don't display in a basic R plot:

```
plot(c(1,2), c(1,3), xlab = "基本", ylab = "收入")
```

I tried adding `family = 'Arial Unicode MS'` to `plot`, and I tried setting `Sys.setlocale("LC_ALL", "zh_CN.UTF-8")` or `Sys.setlocale("LC_ALL", "en_US.UTF-8")` beforehand, each time I get the same plot:
[image]

I use R 4.3.1 and RStudio 2023.09.0 (Build 463) on a Windows 11 PC.

Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: Works fine for me, have locale `en_US.UTF-8`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on your system and the graphics device that you are using. The `ragg` package has graphics devices that do a good job on most fonts on most systems, but they mostly write to a file, they don't display on screen.

RStudio has support for on-screen displays using `ragg`: see https://ragg.r-lib.org/#use-ragg-in-rstudio .  With that enabled you should see your full character sets, provided you have the right fonts installed on your system.

Unfortunately, `ragg` fails on a few font/style combinations, and will leave the characters blank.  If this happens, a workaround is to specify a different font family.  For example, according to the comments the default font failed, but `plot(c(1,2), c(1,3), xlab = "基本", ylab = "收入", family="Microsoft JhengHei")` worked.  This is a known bug, but I don't know when it will be fixed.

Comment: Thank you very much! Changing the graphics parameter to AGG (as indicated in your link) did the trick for the display. However, the Chinese characters are still not correctly displayed when I save the plot to a file. How can I fix that?

Comment: You need to use a device driver from `ragg`.  If you want a PNG file, use `agg_png("filename.png")` before plotting, and the usual `dev.off()` after plotting.  There is also `agg_jpeg` and some less likely ones.  There is no `agg_pdf`, unfortunately.

Comment: I have tried that, and it doesn't work.

Comment: "it doesn't work" is not a useful comment.  Exactly what goes wrong?  Do you get the same image as in your question, or an error, or something else?

Comment: I don't get any error, but instead of the squares, I simply get nothing where the characters should be. The labels appear empty. Also, `dev.off()` returns `RStudioGD 
        2`

Comment: The blanks sound like a bug you could report on the `ragg` web page.  To work around it, you could try using a different font family.  You can see the full list by running `systemfonts::system_fonts()$family`.   Then ask for one using something like `plot(c(1,2), c(1,3), xlab = "基本", ylab = "收入", family="Microsoft JhengHei")`.

Comment: Great, it works! Thanks a lot! Can you edit your answer to add `family="Microsoft JhengHei"`? Also, is there a way to export the figure in PDF?

Comment: I think the only way to make use of this solution in PDF is to include a PNG image in your PDF document, e.g. using R Markdown.  I believe there are other ways to get Chinese characters in PDF from R, but I don't know what they are.

Comment: Alright, thank you. I will do that. It remains an issue as the PNG is quite pixelized, but it is still readable. 
FYI, I had to add `op <- par(family = "Microsoft JhengHei")` before the legend (and `par(op)` afterwards to restore default parameters) to change the legend font style. (Perhaps worth adding in your response). I took this tip from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7136990/how-to-change-font-family-in-a-legend-in-an-r-plot